# eclipse stuck at running program

Tags: android, eclipse

This is the picture after I end task the eclipse.

[image]

My Android Program has no errors, and before this problem it was all fine.
It happened when I added some code into my program. It gets stuck after I click the run button.
This also happens when I run my handphone for debugging the program.
Other programs are all working fine, only one is stuck.

the meaning of my stuck is the progress bar of eclipse keep show `launching myprogram (100%)` but it didn't running out the emulator.

[image]

When I try to remove and import it again seem there is a classes.dex file which I cannot delete, I have to restart my computer for it to allow to delete and I have to force the program to close.
I have searched at this website and they said keep open the emulator but it doesn't work for me.

below is the connecting coding that i added.

```
    //check internet connection
private boolean chkConnectionStatus(){
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
    this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =
    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if( wifi.isAvailable() ){     
      return true;
     }
        else if( mobile.isAvailable() ){      
          return true;        
     }
     else
     { 
         Toast.makeText(this, "Check your internet" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem was solved, it is caused by kaspersky anti-virus.Thank you for all help

Comment: I have the same problem and I also have Kaspersky AntiVirus installed. Could you help me with the steps to workaround it without having to uninstall or disable Kaspersky. Thanks.

Comment: If anyone wants to check out the steps to disable Kaspersky for the purpose of getting out of this problem, please refer to the solution posted here: [Stackoverflow: <Similar Porblem> Classes.dex Causing problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813274/classes-dex-causing-problems/12019093#12019093)

Answer (score 0):

- backtrack the changes you made. (look for a previous version of your code which worked fine, Right Click on the .java file -> compare with - > Local History. )

->build after every change you make. That will help you track the problem.

Comment: i have backup my before coding, i was imported it again. after i adding some coding about the internet connection it will start stuck again..

Comment: the code i already show above, but i think the coding didn't have any problem actually...

Comment: sorry, i can't figure out the problem. But you can use this strategy to track your problems down. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't delete a file on Windows, then a process is using it. You can use a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find the offending process and kill it.

When Eclipse doesn't want to start, try to run it from a command prompt with the options `-console -consoleLog -debug` It will then print information into the console which might help to find the problem.

**[EDIT]** You should not kill Eclipse when the emulator hangs. Instead, kill the emulator process to "unlock" Eclipse. Use a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find child processes of Eclipse if clicking "Terminate Process" in the Console view (in Eclipse) doesn't work.

There are two problems with killing Eclipse:

1. It may not kill the child process. That would lead to locked files
2. Killing Eclipse can corrupt your workspace.

Comment: can i know where is the path should i run? is it inside this path `C:\android-sdk-windows`

Comment: Search for `eclipse.exe` and run that.

Comment: Then why did you post a picture of an Eclipse startup failure?

Comment: that is when i end task the eclipse it pop out that message picture..i do not know what is it..so post it up hope get anything help.

Comment: The error dialog says that you killed Eclipse (`javaw.exe` and `-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product`). If you were running the emulator, I'd expect at least a different product parameter :-/

Comment: ya...because it do not let me close it normally.. i am running my program and it keep running in the eclipse progress as the picture i show, but it did not pop out the emulator..it keep running about an hour also didn't work so i end task the program.

Comment: so now should i re-install the eclipse? actually the problem still there...but now it happen sometime..sometime not

Comment: Reinstall is not necessary but it will be if you continue to kill eclipse. Run the code in the debugger and set a breakpoint so you can see where it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Eclipse with logging enabled (use -console -consoleLog -debug as Aaron mentioned above). Also use the following options in order to get more information on what exactly goes wrong in Eclipse (see for more details (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/3.1/debug.html):

> Eclipse has a log file where problems are recorded and usually this is the first thing that an Eclipse developer asks for when you report a problem. The log file can be found in a couple of places:
>
> **Workspace log** - This is the most common location for the log file, It is stored in your workspace in the meta-data directory. Check out workspace/.metadata/.log.
>
> **Configuration log** - Sometimes information is recored in the configuration log file instead of the workspace log. (especially if the workspace hasn't been created yet, there isn't one, or it cannot be created) Check your configuration area for a configuration log file. (configuration/.log)

Also try running Eclipse using java.exe instead of javaw.exe (for example by adding eclipse -vm \jre\bin\java.exe into eclipse.ini) in order to observe better what happens when Eclipse is running.

The link mentioned above (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/3.1/debug.html) should give you enough options to find out what happens in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank for comment, please see what i chatting with Aaron in the comments, my eclipse is no problem..the message happen when i end task the eclipse.