# apps not running on android emulator/device

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I've asked this already but none of the 2 answers fixed this problem, Now i even tried installing eclipse indigo and install 64 bit jdk, but i just can't get the apps to run! The emulator boots up fast No errors , nothing on console. Even the device chooser wont show up(showed up ONCE). This is the 3rd day im trying this to run.

```
08-04 02:47:12.460: I/Choreographer(395): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 02:47:12.930: D/dalvikvm(395): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2417K, 32% free 15263K/22279K, paused 34ms+11ms, total 171ms
08-04 02:47:13.380: D/dalvikvm(395): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1702K, 31% free 15525K/22279K, paused 31ms+7ms, total 119ms
08-04 02:47:13.380: D/dalvikvm(395): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 49ms
08-04 02:47:13.470: D/dalvikvm(353): GC_CONCURRENT freed 383K, 6% free 8420K/8903K, paused 238ms+546ms, total 1896ms
08-04 02:47:14.050: D/dalvikvm(395): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2028K, 32% free 15307K/22279K, paused 76ms, total 85ms
08-04 02:47:14.440: D/dalvikvm(395): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1816K, 35% free 14690K/22279K, paused 63ms, total 69ms
08-04 02:47:14.760: E/SQLiteLog(496): (1) no such table: files
08-04 02:47:14.960: I/ContactsDatabaseHelper(353): Locale change completed in 80174ms
08-04 02:47:14.960: I/ContactsDatabaseHelper(353): Switching to locale en_US
08-04 02:47:15.050: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
08-04 02:47:15.240: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
08-04 02:47:15.710: E/WVMExtractor(39): Failed to open libwvm.so
08-04 02:47:15.740: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(39): failed to extract an album art
08-04 02:47:15.940: W/MediaProvider(496): no database for scanned volume external
08-04 02:47:16.090: I/MediaProvider(496): Upgrading media database from version 0 to 509, which will destroy all old data
08-04 02:47:16.140: I/ContactsDatabaseHelper(353): Locale change completed in 1174ms
08-04 02:47:16.150: I/ContactsProvider(353): Upgrading aggregation algorithm
08-04 02:47:16.180: I/ContactAggregator(353): Marked all visible contacts for aggregation: 0 raw contacts, 7 ms
08-04 02:47:16.201: I/ContactsProvider(353): Aggregation algorithm upgraded for 0 raw contacts in 33ms
08-04 02:47:16.350: I/ContactsFTS(353): Rebuild contact search index in 106ms, 0 contacts
08-04 02:47:16.600: D/dalvikvm(353): GC_CONCURRENT freed 448K, 6% free 8430K/8967K, paused 36ms+40ms, total 154ms
08-04 02:47:17.400: E/SQLiteLog(496): (1) no such table: album_info
08-04 02:47:17.480: D/dalvikvm(496): GREF has increased to 201
08-04 02:47:17.510: W/MediaScanner(496): Error opening directory '/mnt/sdcard/.android_secure/', skipping: Permission denied.
08-04 02:47:17.710: V/MediaScanner(496): pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@412713a0
08-04 02:47:17.710: V/MediaScanner(496): /pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@412713a0
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496): Exception in handleMessage
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column time is not unique (code 19)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:727)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1665)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1644)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.logToDb(MediaProvider.java:1736)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.delete(MediaProvider.java:3742)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.delete(ContentProvider.java:228)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:956)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerService.scan(MediaScannerService.java:109)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerService.access$300(MediaScannerService.java:49)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(MediaScannerService.java:261)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerService.run(MediaScannerService.java:183)
08-04 02:47:17.990: E/MediaScannerService(496):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-04 02:47:18.050: D/dalvikvm(496): GC_CONCURRENT freed 331K, 5% free 8285K/8711K, paused 97ms+127ms, total 296ms
08-04 02:47:37.340: D/dalvikvm(483): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.340: D/dalvikvm(273): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.340: D/dalvikvm(614): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.340: D/dalvikvm(395): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.340: D/dalvikvm(288): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.350: D/dalvikvm(258): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.350: D/dalvikvm(426): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.350: D/dalvikvm(157): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.350: D/dalvikvm(548): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.350: D/dalvikvm(445): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.360: D/dalvikvm(308): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.360: D/dalvikvm(381): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.360: D/dalvikvm(496): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.360: D/dalvikvm(458): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.360: D/dalvikvm(353): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:47:37.360: D/dalvikvm(531): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 02:50:20.619: D/dalvikvm(288): GC_CONCURRENT freed 356K, 7% free 8597K/9159K, paused 39ms+7ms, total 121ms
08-04 02:56:24.701: E/ThrottleService(157): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-04 02:58:06.359: D/dalvikvm(288): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 7% free 8578K/9159K, paused 77ms+6ms, total 130ms
08-04 03:00:01.560: D/dalvikvm(381): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.570: D/dalvikvm(273): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.570: D/dalvikvm(614): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.570: D/dalvikvm(395): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.580: D/dalvikvm(288): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.580: D/dalvikvm(258): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.580: D/dalvikvm(426): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.580: D/dalvikvm(157): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.590: D/dalvikvm(445): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.590: D/dalvikvm(458): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.590: D/dalvikvm(548): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.590: D/dalvikvm(531): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.600: D/dalvikvm(483): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.600: D/dalvikvm(353): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.610: D/dalvikvm(308): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:00:01.610: D/dalvikvm(496): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-04 03:02:05.292: D/dalvikvm(157): GC_CONCURRENT freed 472K, 46% free 10280K/18951K, paused 76ms+13ms, total 196ms
08-04 03:05:46.020: D/dalvikvm(288): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 7% free 8578K/9159K, paused 33ms+5ms, total 89ms
08-04 03:06:24.740: E/ThrottleService(157): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-04 03:13:22.300: D/dalvikvm(288): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 7% free 8578K/9159K, paused 19ms+5ms, total 87ms
```

EDIT: just now, I tried running it and it worked(it worked also before but mmost of the time it doesn't) and this showed up in the console

```
[2012-08-04 10:21:35 - RunAndroid] ------------------------------
[2012-08-04 10:21:35 - RunAndroid] Android Launch!
[2012-08-04 10:21:35 - RunAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2012-08-04 10:21:35 - RunAndroid] Performing com.example.runandroid.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-08-04 10:21:41 - RunAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

Then the device chooser showed up .The emulator and my device is showed up on the list. As you can see i cancelled it to see if it would run again, then i re ran the program and there, back to it's problem, the device chooser isn't showing up, nothing on console.

Answer (score 1):

Try run AVD Manager.exe independtent,choose an emulator then start,at last run android project in eclipse.

Comment: It didn't work but thanks! i have managed to run some apps a few times(4x) this past 3 days

Comment: click run configurations,attention if something changed when you select a different emulator,if still not work,try to update adt plus and sdk tools.

Comment: what did you mean by",attention if something changed when you select a different emulator"?

Comment: Okay i managed to make it run now. then after modifying my codes, i tried to run it and it didnt run. but i noticed that my app icon is in the applications menu.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the line

[2012-07-11 22:13:58 - ha] No Launcher activity found!
It says no activity has been given Intent-Filter to be MAIN and LAUNCHER Activity of your Application

In AndroidManifest.xml it should look like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".NameOfMainActivity">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

read more here:

[What does it mean "No Launcher activity found!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801371/what-does-it-mean-no-launcher-activity-found)

Comment: I dont have that "no launcher activity found". there's no error shown in the logcat or console at all! except if i kill-server, it says "forced close"

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
08-04 02:47:17.510: W/MediaScanner(496): Error opening directory'/mnt/sdcard/.android_secure/', skipping: Permission denied.
```

Add to manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

give size to sdcard of  emulator/device

Answer (score 0):

Try to run application using following steps, right click on application ->run As->Run configuration-> brows the project->in target select "Always prompt to pick device"-> click apply->click run. try this and let me know what is happening in console and in logcat.

Comment: this is exactly how im doing it. nothing is shown in logcat and console, the device chooser window is not even showing up.

Comment: OK. i think SDK is not install properly. Download it again from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. and install it in this steps. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Comment: Okay thanks, but check my post, ive updated it with the contents inside console and logcat

Comment: Please clean the project and try to run. Its conflicting with class name. Click on Project menu ->  clean-> select project and ok. Let me know what it does.

Comment: Hm. It run the 1st time after cleaning it, then i tried to run it again and it didn't work anymore, thanks!

Comment: Do one thing cloase all other projects in your current workspace. and then try. Now it should 100% work.

Comment: when you said close all other projects, you mean delete them? how do i exactly close it?

Comment: I think i found the problem. I have exactly the same problem as this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428564/eclipse-stuck-at-running-program?answertab=votes#tab-top 

I have kaseprsky installed and i cant delete my classes.dex file, my computer stops responding whenever i try. He said the he was able to fixed it and kaspersky was causing the problem but he didn't explain how

Comment: I cant clean my projects any more, it always get stuck at deleting classes.dex, what should i do? Sometimes im able to clean it but it still wont run, I now even made a new workspace with just a helloworld app in it, but it still wont work. thanks for helping Dhrupal.