# Classes.dex Causing problems

Tags: android, eclipse, security

I can't delete or even right click my classes.dex, when i do "my computer" stops responding. When i try to clean projects using eclipse, the progress stuck when it tries to delete classes.dex. I also tried scanning the bin folder of my app with my anti virus but it also stopped responding when it tried to scan classes.dex. I think this is also the reason I can't run my apps.

Check out this question:
[eclipse stuck at running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428564/eclipse-stuck-at-running-program?answertab=votes#tab-top)

We have the similar problem. He was able to solve it and he said it was caused by kaspersky(i have kaspersky installed) but he did not explain how. I tried to disbale protection with kaspersky and it didn't work.

Comment: Exactly same problem. Someone please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling Kaspersky security seems to work for me. The steps I followed were:

1. Close the emulator, eclipse, and all other windows related to the Android environment.
2. Disconnect from the internet (because I'm paranoid, maybe, and don't want to be connected to the net when I turn off Kaspersky protection).
3. Turn off Kaspersky protection (your system, at this point, will start shouting all sorts of curses at you for turning off its protection and leaving it vulnerable).
4. Run eclipse and start the emulator before doing anything else.
5. Make changes to your code and continue testing your app using the emulator normally (now, the 'getting stuck at launching 100%' problem should stop).
6. If you need the internet/if you need to enable Kaspersky then close the emulator, eclipse, et al.
7. Turn on Kaspersky - acknowledge your system's sigh of relief ;)
8. Connect to the internet and continue browsing.

Hope this helps, and hope it continues working that smoothly for me as well.